# Clear function for Stanford iOS 8 Calculator application

Tags: mvc, ios, calculator, swift

I am following the Stanford iOS 8 lectures and I believe I have successfully added the "Clear" functionality to the application, but I don't know if I am doing it properly.

**Controller**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
    var brain = CalculatorBrain()
    var displayValue: Double
    {
        get
        {
            return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }

        set
        {
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
        }

    }

    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber
        {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        }
        else
        {
            display.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func enter()
    {
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
        if let result = brain.pushOperand(displayValue){ displayValue = result }
        else {displayValue = 0}
    }

    @IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton)
    {
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber{ enter() }
        if let operation = sender.currentTitle
        {
            if let result = brain.performOperation(operation) {displayValue = result}
            else {displayValue = 0}
        }
    }

    // Linked to the "C" button in the Storyboard
    @IBAction func clear()
    {
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
        brain.clear()
        displayValue = 0
    }
```

**Model**

```
import Foundation

class CalculatorBrain
{

    private enum Op: Printable
    {
        case Operand(Double)
        case UnaryOperation(String, Double -> Double)
        case BinaryOperation(String, (Double, Double) -> Double)

        var description: String
        {
            get
            {
                switch self
                {
                case .Operand(let operand): return "\(operand)"
                case .UnaryOperation(let symbol, _): return symbol
                case .BinaryOperation(let symbol, _): return symbol
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var opStack = [Op]()
    private var knownOps = [String: Op]()

    init()
    {
        knownOps["×"] = Op.BinaryOperation("×", *)
        knownOps["÷"] = Op.BinaryOperation("÷") { $1 / $0 }
        knownOps["+"] = Op.BinaryOperation("+", +)
        knownOps["−"] = Op.BinaryOperation("−") { $1 - $0 }
        knownOps["√"] = Op.UnaryOperation("√", sqrt)
    }

    private func evaluate(ops: [Op]) -> (result: Double?, remainingOps: [Op])
    {
        if !ops.isEmpty {
            var remainingOps = ops
            let op = remainingOps.removeLast()
            switch op {

            case .Operand(let operand):
                return (operand, remainingOps)

            case .UnaryOperation(_, let operation):
                let operandEvaluation = evaluate(remainingOps)
                if let operand = operandEvaluation.result
                {
                    return (operation(operand), operandEvaluation.remainingOps)
                }

            case .BinaryOperation(_, let operation):
                let op1Evaluation = evaluate(remainingOps)
                if let operand1 = op1Evaluation.result
                {
                    let op2Evaluation = evaluate(op1Evaluation.remainingOps)
                    if let operand2 = op2Evaluation.result
                    {
                        return (operation(operand1, operand2), op2Evaluation.remainingOps)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (nil, ops)
    }

    func evaluate() -> Double?
    {
        let (result, remainder) = evaluate(opStack)
        println("\(opStack) = \(result) with \(remainder) left over")
        return result
    }

    func pushOperand(operand: Double) -> Double?
    {
        opStack.append(Op.Operand(operand))
        return evaluate()
    }

    func performOperation(symbol: String) -> Double?
    {
        if let operation = knownOps[symbol] { opStack.append(operation) }
        return evaluate()
    }

    func clear()
    {
        opStack = [Op]()
        evaluate()
    }
}
```

And my log output is:

> ```
> [8.0] = Optional(8.0) with [] left over
> [8.0, 9.0] = Optional(9.0) with [8.0] left over
> [8.0, 9.0, ×] = Optional(72.0) with [] left over
> [8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0] = Optional(2.0) with [8.0, 9.0, ×] left over
> [8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0, −] = Optional(70.0) with [] left over
> [8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0, −, 5.0] = Optional(5.0) with [8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0, −] left over
> [8.0, 9.0, ×, 2.0, −, 5.0, ÷] = Optional(14.0) with [] left over
> [] = nil with [] left over
> ```

I am pretty sure the last line in the log output is correct.  Basically I was just hoping someone with more iOS/MVC experience could tell me whether or not I implemented the `clear` functionality correctly.  If I didn't, how might I go about fixing my code?

Comment: Okay, it's just a lot of code for a small function.  The only code I wrote is the two `clear` functions in the Model and the Controller.  Everything else was provided in the lecture demo from Stanford.

Comment: I don't have it on GitHub yet.  The code isn't that long I guess, so I just added it in.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> func clear()
> {
>     opStack = [Op]()
>     evaluate()
> }
> ```

I'm just going to review this method for now.  You said in comments that most of this code was provided from a lecture and the primary task was implementing this method.

First of all, calling `evaluate()` seems particularly unuseful.  `evaluate()` doesn't actually change anything about the state of the operation stack.  All we get out of this is the `println` statement.  Given that this is an iOS app, `println` is going to be just wasted processor time (and should be eliminated from release builds).  The only reason to call `evaluate` is if you're going to do something with its return value.

---

Additionally, rather than creating a *new* array, why don't we just empty the existing array?

```
opStack.removeAll()
```

---

So, our final implementation should either care or not care about what `evaluate()` returns.

If we choose to care, we should make `evaluate()` more like the other methods were we are pushing buttons other than `clear`:

```
func clear() -> Double? {
    opStack.removeAll()
    return evaluate()
}
```

In this case, `evaluate()` and therefore `clear()` *should* always return `nil`, but it might be useful for unit testing to go ahead and return the value.  We can always `assert` the `nil`-ness in unit testing.

```
assert(clear() == nil, "clear() must return nil.")
```

If we choose to not care, calling `evaluate` is unnecessary:

```
func clear() {
    opStack.removeAll()
}
```

---

**ADDENDUM:** I'm also going to argue in your view controller that we shouldn't ever need to write the line `displayValue = 0`.  I know that it happens throughout the provided code, but I don't consider it all that great.  In all cases with the `if let`/`else`, it would be simply to just write:

```
displayValue = brain.performOperation(operation) ?? 0
```

instead of the big `if let`/`else` which we've smushed down to save lines.

In the case of your implementation of the `clear()` `@IBAction` method, it's fine as is if we leave our `clear()` with no return value.  However, if we give it a return value, we should repeat our use of Swift's *`nil`-coalescing operator*:

```
displayValue = clear() ?? 0
```

Answer (score 3):

(Also a beginner following Stanford CS193p 2015.)

Two slightly different solutions here somewhere between steveclark's and nhgrif's. My `@IBACTION` in `ViewController` code is the same in both of my versions. In each case the `newValue` of `displayValue` is being returned as follows -

In `ViewController`:

```
@IBAction func cancel() {
    displayValue = brain.cancel()
}
```

In `CalculatorBrain`:

```
    func cancel() -> Double {
        opStack = [Op]()
        return 0
    }
```

In the same lecture we are also tasked with adapting the code so that displayValue is a `Double?` - and it knows what to do with a `nil` value. So in another version of my answer to the same question which steveclark is addressing here I had the following -

In `CalculatorBrain`:

```
func cancel() -> Double? {
    opStack = [Op]()
    return evaluate()
}
```

The second version returns a `nil` which the `diplayValue` `set` knows what to do with.

Comment: `return 0` isn't very useful in the first attempt.  Instead, perhaps we should `return evaluate() ?? 0` which will make sure `evaluate()` isn't returning a number.  The `?? 0` allows us to keep the return type as `Double` instead of `Double?` as it'll return `0` any time `evaulate()` gives us `nil`.

Comment: I'm also going to suggest you take a look at my answer in which I'm calling `removeAll()` on the array rather than creating a new array.

Comment: With all that said though, welcome to Code Review.  This is a very good first answer.

Comment: Have already incorporate `removeAll()` into my code. Thanks for that.

Comment: Not in the answer here?  That's what I was pointing at.

Comment: If think that in this task it is ok to have `evaluate()` simply return a `nil` - since in this lecture we are also tasked with having `displayValue` in `ViewController` be a `Double?` and for it to know what to do with a `nil`. That seems to be what the lecturer Paul Hegarty is encouraging us towards. But I may be wrong. Thanks for helping with this - and to steveclark for asking the original question.